# Install gulp on the project issue

Tags: npm

I am trying to install the gulp into my project folder.But when I run this command to install the gulp I get following error:

```
Sab-MacBook-Pro:myproject sab$ npm install gulp -save-dev
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp" "-save-dev"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path /Users/sab/RubymineProjects/myproject/node_modules/gulp
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/sab/RubymineProjects/myproject/node_modules/gulp' -> '/Users/sab/RubymineProjects/myproject/node_modules/.gulp.DELETE'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/sab/RubymineProjects/myproject/npm-debug.log
Sab-MacBook-Pro:myproject sab$
```

If I am not wrong the error message is due to existing gulp folder.But when I look into the my project node_module folder the gulp folder is not there.

Comment: If you can, delete de folder and start over. If you create a new fresh folder, and run the command on the new created folder, you get the same message?

you type the command on "Sab-MacBook-Pro:myproject sab$" and the last line is "Sab-MacBook-Pro:firmlogic sab$" how did it change the folder?

Comment: It is same directory is just edit my question.Sorry for confusion.Do you mean delete the whole node_modules folder?I cannot do that because i have other installation on this folder.

Comment: deleting the `node_modules` directory should be ok. Presumably, all of your dependencies are specified in the `package.json` file - so if you delete `node_modules` and then run `npm install` again, it should download everything you need

Comment: Thanks it works like charm. You guys are life saver. :)